# Download GitLab Generic Package File anonymously and in readOnly mode through GitLab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a generic package file in Package Registry and that package is attached to a Release as a package.

I got succeeded to upload/publish and download a package using Generic API using curl commands, Python or C# code but in order to do so a private token is needed.

My app is going to be distributed to customers and my app is downloading that package on the fly so.... it forces me to provide the private token and the whole url containing project ID, etc. in source code... so if an attacker decompiles it... the attacker gets access to that private token and url and have access to Gitlab to perform operations on my project through the GitLab API and I don't want this.

I know that i can create private tokens based on role and grants, but i would like to know if there is some specific role and grants combination to only allow customers access anonymously and in readonly mode to download the package and don't allow them to do other operations than download.